# is it technically wrong to write $(\lvert x\rvert)^2$ as $(x)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

kind of a simple question , I know, but just in case I'm wrong

is writing an absolute value necessary when said absolute value is squared?

for example something like this:

$(\lvert x-3\rvert)^2 = (x-3)^2$

since absolute value functions can be written as

$\lvert x \rvert = \sqrt{(x)^2}$

I thought that maybe $ (\lvert x \rvert)^2 = (\sqrt{(x)^2})^2 $ and the square root cancels out ,making $(x)^2$

thanks

Comment: For real $x$, it is absolutely fine to write $|x|^2=x^2$. For complex x, these two have different meaning.

Comment: No, it's not wrong.

Comment: okay, thanks. I'm not dealing  with complex numbers or vectors, so it works then

Comment: It is a basic result that on $\mathbf R$, $\;\lvert x\rvert^2=x^2$. Of course this is wrong on $\mathbf C$.

Comment: For vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ writing $|x|^2 = x \cdot x = x^2$ can be motivated by geometric algebra:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, it is not the case that $|A|^2 = A^2$ (for example, if $A$ is a complex number, or a vector, or some other kind of object where some notions of absolute values and squaring make sense).  However, if $A$ is a real number, then you are fine.

Comment: ok , thanks. real numbers is what I'm dealing with right now so I'll just write it like that

Comment: However for a vector you have an analog: $\lVert A\rVert^2=A\cdot A$.